# Convert Color type to string when returning in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've got a model with a Color type in it that I'm returning in ASP .NET MVC.

When I return it, I want to return it just as a string (such as Hex value). Is there a way to do this other than just changing the Color type to String?

Right now it returns as such:

```
<background_color xmlns:d4p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Drawing">
<d4p1:knownColor>0</d4p1:knownColor>
<d4p1:name i:nil="true"/>
<d4p1:state>2</d4p1:state>
<d4p1:value>4294967295</d4p1:value>
</background_color>
```

I'd like to have it return as:

```
<background_color>FFFFFF</background_color>
```

Cheers!

Comment: Is there a reason you want to do the conversion in the view rather than allowing the controller to handle it for you (as is normal to MVC)?

Comment: Not fully sure what you mean? Its a Web API that needs to conform to a specific format, so it just returns the Model straight up.

Comment: In the end _something_ is going to have to perform the conversion and leaving the overhead to the view is less than desirable. You'll either need to ensure it occurs in the MVC controller or the web API (which fills the role of the controller). In both situations it's best to handle it outside of the UI as such formatting is typically a business concern rather than a UI concern.

Comment: Hm, either I'm not asking the right question or I'm misunderstanding you...

Comment: Hi, can u share your code in view , model and the webApi